# Construct the univalent analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Construct the univalent analytic function $w=f(z)$ that satisfy

- $f: \{z:\lvert z\rvert < 1, Im\ z \ge 0\}\rightarrow \{w: Im\ w \ge 0\}$
- $f(1)=-1$
- $f(-1)=1$
- $f(0)=\infty$

I try some methods but get confused.

One is that we can determine the linear fractional transformation that maps $z_1,z_2,z_3$ to $w_1,w_2,w_3$ is  $\frac{w-w_1}{w-w_2}\cdot\frac{w_3-w_2}{w_3-w_1}=\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\cdot\frac{z_3-z_2}{z_3-z_1}$. But such a method does not  guarantee that condition 1 holds.

Another method is use a unit dist as a bridge. $F:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{H} \quad F(t)=i\frac{1-t}{1+t}$ and we have $F(i)=1,F(-i)=-1, F(-1)=\infty$, and then try to figure out another transformation $G:\{z:\lvert z\rvert < 1, Im\ z>0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ that satisfy $G(1)=-i, G(-1)=i, G(0)=-1$. But I am stuck with it here. Should I use $\ln z$ to map the half disk to half stripe, and then $z^2$ to the stripe and $e^z$ to the half plane?

I also wonder if there is a pipeline for these problems, e.g., some useful transformation and a path for trail. I know some of them like

- $\mathbb{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}: w(z)=e^{i\theta}\frac{z-z_0}{z-\overline{z_0}}, w(z_0)=0,w(\overline(z_0))=\infty$
- $\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{H}: w(z)=i\frac{1-z}{1+z}$
- $\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}: w(z)=e^{i\theta}\frac{z-z_0}{1-z\overline{z_0}}, w(z_0)=0$
- $\{z:0<Im\ z<\pi\}\rightarrow\mathbb{H}: w(z)=e^z$

But I still fail to solve the problems sometimes.

Comment: If your domain is $\{z:|z|<1,Im\  z>0\}$ then why $f(1)$ and $f(-1)$ make sense?

Comment: Maybe the questioner makes some mistake here, I think the real axis should be included

Comment: I'm not sure about that though... Analytic functions are often defined on an open set of the plane... Perhaps the questioner used $f(1)$ for $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)$.